# using tooltipster to display tool tips as part of innerHTML for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I am using [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) to generate tool tips. All works fine except in the situation where I need to set the contents of a div based on user input using a simple JavaScript function. The div contents consists of images, when hovering over each image, a tool tip should display. However, the tip displays as the default browser behaves for displaying title= with an image. The JavaScript I use is simple:

```
function setAwards() {
var awardsdiv=document.getElementById("awards"); awardsdiv.innerHTML="";
if (document.setvalues.superstar.checked == true) awardsdiv.innerHTML=awardsdiv.innerHTML + "<img class=\"tooltip\" title=\"Description of award\" width=\"16\" src=\"/pix/superstar.png\" alt=\"[ Super Star ]\" />";
[... stuff removed ...]
}
```

Is there a way to make this work? Tool tips do display elsewhere on this web page, so the resources needed appear to be set up correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize the tooltip (`$(...).tooltipster({...})`) after you have inserted your new HTML content or use delegation.

For "automatic" initialization, you might want to use delegated event listeners for that, see https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/499

Comment: I inserted:

    <script>
    $('body').on('mouseenter', '.tooltip:not(.tooltipstered)', function(){
        $(this)
        .tooltipster({theme: 'tooltipster-custom',contentAsHTML: true,position: 'bottom'})
            .tooltipster('show');
    });  
    </script>

right after the body tag, and this indeed worked. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer to close this question.